# Simpler formula for showing an application is linear?

Tags: linear-algebra

In order to prove that an application $f$ is linear, we are told to show that:
$$(1)~~~~
\forall u,v\in \mathbb R^n.\;
\forall \lambda,\mu \in \mathbb R.\;
f(\lambda u + \mu v) = \lambda f(u) + \mu f(v)
$$

But I feel like this second $\mu$ variable is unnecessary, and we could simply show:

$$(2)~~~~
\forall u,v\in \mathbb R^n.\;
\forall \lambda \in \mathbb R.\;
f(\lambda u + v) = \lambda f(u) + f(v)
$$

Indeed, by taking $\lambda = 1$ we get the first requirement:
$\forall u,v\in \mathbb R^n.\;
f(u + v) = f(u) + f(v)
$.

Now, suppose $f({\bf 0}) = k \neq {\bf 0}$.
Then $f(\lambda {\bf 0} + v) = f(v) = \lambda k + f(v)$,
which leads to a contradiction for any $\lambda \neq {\bf 0}$ (and $n > 0$). So we have $f({\bf 0}) = {\bf 0}$.

Therefore, by taking $v = {\bf 0}$ in $(2)$ we get the second requirement: 
$f(\lambda u) = \lambda f(u)$.

Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, what you have said is true. In fact it works if we pick any $\mu\ne0$ (though picking $\mu=1$ like you did is the most straightforward to prove).

Suppose we have $\forall u,v\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $\forall \lambda\in\mathbb{R}$, $\mu\in\mathbb{R},\mu\ne0$ (that is the same as in the original set up except with some fixed nonzero $\mu$)
$$f(\lambda u+\mu v)=\lambda f(u)+\mu f(v)$$

Setting $u,v=0$, we get
$$f(0)=\lambda f(0)+\mu f(0)=(\lambda+\mu)f(0)$$
Hence $\forall\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ we have 
$$(\lambda+\mu-1)f(0)=0$$
so we can conclude $f(0)=0$.

Now we just set $u=0$, achieving

$$f(\mu v)=\lambda f(0)+\mu f(v)=\mu f(v)$$

In particular this tells us $$f(\mu(u+v))=\mu f(u+v)$$

Now setting $\lambda=\mu$, we have
$$f(\mu u+\mu v)=\mu f(u)+\mu f(v)$$
but from above we also have that this is $\mu f(u+v)$, so
$$\mu f(u+v)=\mu f(u)+\mu f(v)$$
and we can cancel $\mu$ from both sides (since it is nonzero) to finally get
$$f(u+v)=f(u)+f(v)$$
and we can finish off the proof as you did by letting $v=0$ getting
$$f(\lambda v)=\lambda f(v)$$